# How to find vertices exist in all possible route between 2 specific vertex in a directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

How to find the common vertices in all possible routes between 2 specific vertices in a directed graph? At least one route exist is a prerequisite.

Comment: may I ask why do you need that? what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Is O(|V| |E|) good enough?

Comment: I prefer a solution better than O(|V||E|). I am learning static code analysis. When a log is output, I need to found out the common vertices exist in all path reach the log, and mark them as must run statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`O(|V||E|)` solution. **A** and **B** - end of routes.

1. Iterate over all vertices.
2. Remove vertex from graph.
3. Check that path exist from **A** to **B** (i.e. with DFS)
4. If path don't exist - vertex is common for all routes.

Comment: Is there a more quick solution? The O(|V||E|) solution is the most plain one.

Answer (score 0):

The only way a vertex will be in all possible paths is if it's a 'bottleneck' - all paths go through it because it's the only way to go.

You can determine which vertices are in this set by removing each from the graph and testing if there still exists a path through the graph. By removing the node, you're looking to see if this removes all viable paths from the source to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a variation of Bellman-Ford that checks whether the vertex is used in all of the possibilities.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how you could adapt Bellman-Ford in this way

Answer (score -1):

Take the intersection of all possible routes.

Comment: Full bidirectional graph - more than n! number of routes

Comment: Didn't say it was fast; put about as much effort into the answer as the OP did in the question.